# Time to second failure of independent exponential lifetimes

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, exponential-distribution, exponential-family

This maybe an easy question, but as I am a beginner, I need help.

Suppose that an electronic system contains $n$ similar components that function independently of each other and that are connected in *a special type of series connection* so that the system fails as soon as **$two$** of the components fail i.e. the system will continue
to operate until two components have failed and break down as soon as any two components have failed. Suppose also that the length of life of each component, measured in hours, has the *exponential* distribution with mean $\mu$. Determine the mean and the variance of the length of time until the system fails.

My working:

Now I took the $n$ components to be $X_i ,i\in{(1,..,n)}$. $\therefore$ $X_i$ **~** $Exp(\frac{1}{\mu})$ . Now if I were given to calculate the probability that $P(X_1\gt{t},X_2\gt{t},...,X_n\gt{t})$ it is easy. Here $t$ is the time during which the machine must run. Yes, I have to add $n$ times( as $i.i.d.$) the conditional probability that $X_1$ has failed while all others are working to get the actual time . But I am at a loss as how to calculate the $expectation$ and $variance$. Please someone help me...

Comment: You are interested order statistics and more especially in the distribution of the second smallest value.
This question is similar to the one here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/80475/order-statistics-of-i-i-d-exponentially-distributed-sample

Comment: I have deleted my answer since you don't find it to be useful. Let $Y > 0$ denote the time of failure (a.k.a. length of life)
of the entire system.  You say that you know how to calculate $P\{Y > t\}$ for any $t > 0$. If you remember that $P\{Y > t\} = 1 - F_Y(t)$, you should be able to find the density $f_Y(t)$ of $Y$ and hence the mean and variance of $Y$.

Comment: I will say something referring to your previous answer(which you have deleted) if you remember. The $F_Y(t)$ specially.Should I proceed by integrating $F_Y(t)$ over 0 to infinity (as that is the range of your $t$ ) Or something else? I know its a silly doubt but please help....Is there any other way round?

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate : The above comment refers to you. I want to find expectation first.